# How to partition timestamp duration in multiple rows using PostgreSQL 9.5?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table 'ad' in my postgres DB containing 'start' and 'end' columns like:

```
ID        Start                   End
1         2003-06-07 00:00:00     2004-09-30 23:59:59
```

How could I break this duration (from 2003 to 2004) in two parts so that start and end dates (timestamps) should remain in the same year like this?

```
ID        Start                   End
1_2003       2003-06-07 00:00:00     2003-12-31 23:59:59
1_2004       2004-01-01 00:00:00     2004-09-30 23:59:59
```

I was wondering whether window function would be helpful in achieving this? I am using PostgreSQL version 9.5 (x64).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data:

```
create table ad (id text, start_t timestamp, end_t timestamp);
insert into ad values
(1, '2003-06-07 00:00:00', '2004-09-30 23:59:59'),
(2, '2002-02-02 00:00:00', '2004-04-04 23:59:59');
```

Query:

```
select 
    concat(id, '_', y) id, 
    case 
        when extract(year from start_t)::int = y then start_t 
        else make_timestamp(y, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) end as "start",
    case 
        when extract(year from end_t)::int = y then end_t 
        else make_timestamp(y, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59) end as "end"
from 
    ad, 
    generate_series(extract(year from start_t)::int, extract(year from end_t)::int) y;

   id   |        start        |         end         
--------+---------------------+---------------------
 1_2003 | 2003-06-07 00:00:00 | 2003-12-31 23:59:59
 1_2004 | 2004-01-01 00:00:00 | 2004-09-30 23:59:59
 2_2002 | 2002-02-02 00:00:00 | 2002-12-31 23:59:59
 2_2003 | 2003-01-01 00:00:00 | 2003-12-31 23:59:59
 2_2004 | 2004-01-01 00:00:00 | 2004-04-04 23:59:59
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you! What if columns 'start' and 'end' in my postgres db are initially stored as text character string i.e., character varying (20)? Do I have to CAST their data type beforehand?

Comment: You should cast varchar to timestamp, on the assumption the varchar values have a proper format of course. I'd suggest to alter column types to timestamp in the table to make life easier in the future.

Comment: For your sample data, the query worked well. But for my data I am getting ERROR: column reference "y" is ambiguous. Can you tell me why? I have altered columns types to timestamp using to_timestamp() function.

Comment: I ran Select extract(year from start_t)::int = y from my_table and it returned logical false. Is something wrong in assignment?

Comment: All your troubles stem from wrong column types. You really should try first to alter the types in the table. I'm not able to debug queries I don't see.

Comment: You are so right. I created a new table, inserted values manually into it and this query worked like a magic! Thank you =)